# Given template: how to add roman page number to abstract footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, templates, abstract

I am working with the following template:

https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.2

(Please extract and compile *thesis.tex*)

With respect to the abstract (`\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}`) I am desperately trying to add the roman page number to the abstract's footer. In fact, if the abstract goes over 2 or more pages I want the page number always to be in the footer (please generate some random lorem ipsum for this purpose). Example:

[image]

I tried using `\thispagestyle{plain}` within the abstract environment or to change the `\newenvironment{abstract}` command in `classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` (line 1137) but without any success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code chunk directly before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract} {
% Normal abstract in the thesis
  \cleardoublepage
  \setsinglecolumn
  \chapter*{\centering \Large Abstract}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage}
}
\makeatother
```

This still leaves the headrule. Removing that will draw you even further from the CUED thesis office requirements. 
Option `abstract` functionality was removed and will not work anymore.